# Rename similar files using Python

Tags: python

I've a list of images that i would like to rename, which represent multiple runs, each run is in a separate folder, so there are similar file names in each of the folders and each folder has a similar file name apart from a different number inside the file name i.e Position014 (RGB rendering) - 1024 x 1024 x 1 x 1 - 3 ch (8 bits).tif Is it possible to rename the file to Position14 followed by the directory name i.e Position14_foldername, and change the extension to a png format. I have started looking at this code but not sure where to go from there if anyone could kindly help.

```
import os
import shutil
from os import path

def main():
    # make a duplicate of an existing file
    if path.exists("Position014 (RGB rendering) - 1024 x 1024 x 1 x 1 - 3 ch (8 bits).tif"):
    # get the path to the file in the current directory
        src = path.realpath("Position014 (RGB rendering) - 1024 x 1024 x 1 x 1 - 3 ch (8 bits).tif");
        
    # rename the original file
        os.rename('Position014 (RGB rendering) - 1024 x 1024 x 1 x 1 - 3 ch (8 bits).tif','Position014.png') 
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You cannot magically turn a TIF file into PNG by renaming it.

Comment: But you can change the name. Which folder name should be added? Just the parent folder's name? I think you can simply manipulate the `'Position014.png'` string in a variable using some string functions before you call `os.rename`

Comment: Thanks! Yes - Just the parent folder would do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work (just to show the idea):

```
import re           # add this to your other imports

src = path.realpath("Position014 (RGB rendering) - 1024 x 1024 x 1 x 1 - 3 ch (8 bits).tif")

folder = src.split(os.sep)[-2]
print(folder)     # just for demonstration

name_elements = re.findall(r'(Position)(\d+)', src)[0]
name = name_elements[0] + str(int(name_elements[1]))
print(name)       # just for demonstration

dst = folder + '_' + name + ".png"
print(dst)

os.rename('Position014 (RGB rendering) - 1024 x 1024 x 1 x 1 - 3 ch (8 bits).tif', dst)
```

I used a regular expression to find 'Position' and '014' so 014 could be transformed into 14.

Comment: Which library i need to define to use src.split. I get an error messag "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rename.py", line 6, in <module>
    folder = src.split(os.sep)[-2]
NameError: name 'src' is not defined"

Comment: I'm sorry, src should be the original file name as you defined in your own code. Changed my answer with that.

Comment: That's great. That's exactly what i am wanting to do. Sorry last question! If i want to apply a loop so it goes through a list of file what is the best way to do this. Thanks